# Under which if any c standards are local functions permitted

Tags: c, function, language-lawyer, nested-function

I have code similar to this

```
int  myfunction (int param)
{
  void tidyup( void)
  {
    // free dynamically allocated memory 
  }

while (1) {
// some Processing

  if error {
    tidyup();
    return -1;
  }
  If success { 

    tidyup();

    return 1;

    }

// further processing

  } // end while 1

}
```

`gcc` with setting `-Wall` doesn't complain, but I read that local functions are illegal in c.

This is a c question,  not c#,c++ c.net etc.

Answer (score 2):

Nested functions are a GCC extension, not really part of any standard:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html

I honestly don't know if any other compilers support that feature.

Answer (score 2):

Local functions or nested functions are not specified in C standard. According to C standard, any function definition needs to appear outside of any other function definition.

However, They are supported as a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).